# “I just can’t solve this easy puzzle!”

Tags: word-property

“Yuh can’t solve this easy puzzle?”

        
         
“Bah, it’s already solved!”

“Nah, it’s *so easy* it only *looks* solved.”

$   \require{begingroup}\begingroup
\def \a            #1#2#3{  \abc  {three}{#1}{nine}  {#2}{thirteen}{#3} }
 \def \b           #1#2#3{ &&\abc  {five}{#1}{seven} {#2}{fourteen}{#3} }
  \def \c          #1#2#3{ && \abc{eight}{#1}{eleven}{#2}{seventeen}{#3} }
   \def \abc #1#2#3#4#5#6{ \phantom {\sf#1} \llap{\sf#2}
                           {\small\, +\, }   \rlap{\sf#4} \phantom{\sf#3}
                           { \small\,= \;}
                              \rlap                        {\sf\,  #6\,  }
                               \rlap{\underline{\hphantom  { \sf\, #6 \, }}}
                                      \hphantom{ \underline{  \sf\,#5  \,}} }
\bbox[darkgreen,5pt]{\color{lightyellow}{\begin{matrix}
\raise.5ex\strut
\a{  one}{ten }{eleven  } \b{ six}{seven}{thirteen} \c{  six}{eleven}{seventeen}
\\
\a{  two}{ten }{twelve  } \b{five}{nine }{fourteen} \c{eight}{nine  }{seventeen}
\\
\a{  six}{six }{twelve  } \b{ six}{eight}{fourteen} \c{eight}{ten   }{eighteen }
\\
\a{three}{ten }{thirteen} \b{five}{ten  }{fifteen } \c{ nine}{nine  }{eighteen }
\\
\a{ four}{nine}{thirteen} \b{ six}{nine }{fifteen } \c{  ten}{ten   }{twenty   }
\raise-.5ex\strut
\end{matrix}}}
\endgroup
$

“Ah, and it isn’t even completely posed.”

         
         
“?”

“Uh, it’s missing an entry.”

         
         
“Oh?   Ohh.   Yeahhh.   Too easy.”

***What entry is missing?***

Comment: I know the pattern but I can't find another that fits for my life :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil You and me both! :)

Comment: All I know is I'll probably be kicking myself when someone gets it :P. [I don't think I'm meant for this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54175228#54175228) lol

Comment: In light of @Stiv's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97466), the font choice (where the summands are set in upright type, and the sum is set in badly-spaced slanted type (as a result of being in math mode)) is deceptive, I think.  Would you be amenable to putting all the words in upright type?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out how
the oddly-spaced italics look sloppy by accident, @LSpice .
It was a whimsically deliberate attempt to evoke
a rudimentary handwritten fill-in-the-blanks classroom exercise.
So the writing is now all upright, as you suggest,
but also on a green background to resemble a chalkboard.
Deception, though, is fairly essential to this particular puzzle
as its impression is meant progress
from apparent simplicity to possible defectiveness
and back to surprising simplicity.

Comment: I think that looks way better!

Comment: This is a nice puzzle, but from a presentation point of view... and easier way to communicate that "order is inconsequential", rather than saying it explicitly at the bottom, would be to just list the entries in order.

Comment: Hah, @JackM , your suggestion to reorder the entries
not only eliminates a note i was never fond of
but it also makes the supposedly-already-solved puzzle look even easier.  Thank you twice over.
(It also provided an opportunity to remove the other note.
 By now, both notes have served their purpose to ward off
 unintended false leads.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the rule as explained in [the other answer](/a/97466/93) —

> the sums work not only as numbers but also as wordlengths

— other possible equations are

> fifty+fifty=one hundred

and

> sixty+forty=one hundred

(not to mention numerous trivial examples along the lines of

> three thousand two+twenty=three thousand twenty-two,

which I guess don't count).

Comment: Uniqueness is part of the criterion for this puzzle. How would you include either one of those answers while preserving uniqueness?

Comment: @Galen, then I guess the puzzle was ill-contrived: If the rule is indeed a stated in the other answer, then there _isn't_ uniqueness.

Comment: Yeah, maybe so. Stiv constrains their answer to summands between and including 1 and 10, *but* I can see how it is pretty trivial for create unions of other intervals that give one answer. This puzzle could use some refinement.

Comment: I think the rule is only numbers which are singular words are used. This would rule out all other possibilities

Comment: ^vote with a note: @msh210, very nice extrapolation(!) though it would help to restate the rule from the other answer, both for completeness and in case that answer changes.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil As would arbitrary unions of other intervals, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 47):

In this puzzle, all of the sums:

> Involve numbers between 1 and 20* (inclusive), where the total number of letters in the numbers being added together equals the number of letters in their resulting sum.
>
>  For example, '*one + ten = eleven*' is involved in this list because 'one' has 3 letters, 'ten' has 3 letters, and 'eleven' has 3+3=6 letters.
>
>  <sub>*Note that the '1 to 20' criterion avoids the need to enter arguments about whether to consider numbers whose names are spelled out using 'more than one word' (requiring either spaces or hyphenation). Remember, we are seeking a **unique** entry that can be added to this set (as the OP's use of '*an entry*' implies that we seek only **one** answer). If we assume no number greater than 20 can be involved, we can totally avoid the need to debate the many potential 'multi-word' equations like '*ten + eleven = twenty one*' or '*ten + twelve = twenty two*' (wherein both sides have 9 letters).</sub>

However, try as I might (and having applied some pretty strict criteria) I just could not find another pair of numbers which could belong to this set - no matter which new combination of two numbers I tested, it seemed that the set was already totally complete! I debated loosening my criteria, widening my search... And then it finally hit me!

> The missing member of the set *isn't* a sum involving a *pair* of numbers - it involves a **triple**!

This way, the entry which is uniquely missing from this list is:

> $$one + six + ten = seventeen$$
>  ...as each side of this equation has 9 letters in total. After all, who said anything about the left-hand side having to have just 2 terms??!

Very clever - had me thinking for a loooong time there!

Comment: Ahhhhhh thats what I was missing :P +1

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I cannot put into words how much I had to rack my brains for this one! I went through the list SO MANY TIMES. humn: That was DEVIOUS - well played :)

Comment: Not exactly 1 to 10; look at the first entry in the third column. But otherwise +1

Comment: @shoover Oops, typo - thanks! :)

Comment: *Twenty-one* **is** a single word.

Answer (score 8):

I assume it's for positive numbers that less and equal to 20. (Since `twenty one` has space).
Here is Python code for solving this question:

> At first, I thought it uses two numbers only:

```
text = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty"]
number = list(range(1,21))

result = set()
for i in range(len(text)):
    for j in range(len(text)):
        num1 = number[i]
        num2 = number[j]
        summ = num1 + num2
        if summ in number and len(text[i]) + len(text[j]) == len(text[summ-1]):
            if text[i] < text[j]:
                res = f"{text[i]} + {text[j]} = {text[summ-1]}"
            else:
                res = f"{text[j]} + {text[i]} = {text[summ-1]}"
            result.add(res)
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

> But the questions already includes all two numbers, so I try three numbers:

```
text = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty"]
number = list(range(1,21))

result = set()
for i in range(len(text)):
    for j in range(len(text)):
        for k in range(len(text)):
            num1 = number[i]
            num2 = number[j]
            num3 = number[k]
            summ = num1 + num2 + num3
            if summ in number and len(text[i]) + len(text[j]) + len(text[k]) == len(text[summ-1]):
                t = [text[i], text[j], text[k]]
                t.sort()
                res = " + ".join(t) + " = " + text[summ-1]
                result.add(res)
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

And got the answer:

> one + six + ten = seventeen

And:

> There won't be solutions for more than 3, since minimum length is 3, 4 numbers minimum length is 12, which is longer than any numbers.

Comment: I absolutely love your Python answers! I'm learning Python myself and its great to see applicability!